# How to Lift State Up w/ React Router 6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am wondering how to share state between my two routes. Should I lift state up from my `AddContact` component to `Layout` or `App` to share to `ContactList`. My `Layout` component is just rendering a `Header` and `Outlet` component.

```
function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([])

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path='/' element={<ContactList />} />
          <Route path='/add' element={<AddContact />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if the parent is the App or the Layout. The Layout is a parent route of ContactList and AddContact so I was confused if I have to pass the state to Layout first then the two children routes or could I pass it straight to the two children routes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could lift it to either.

If lifting state to `App` you can pass what you need down as props to each routed component.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<ContactList contacts={contacts} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/add"
            element={<AddContact setContacts={setContacts} />}
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

The alternative is to locate the state in the `Layout` layout route component and expose via the `Outlet` component's context. The routed components would access the provided context value via the [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) hook.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<ContactList />} />
          <Route path="/add" element={<AddContact />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

```
const Layout = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  return (
    ...
    <Outlet context={{ contacts, setContacts }} />
    ...
  );
};
```

```
const ContactList = () => {
  const { contacts } = useOutletContext();

  ...
};
```

```
const AddContact = () => {
  const { setContacts } = useOutletContext();

  ...
};
```

It basically comes down to preference, or scope in my opinion, e.g. how much of the sub-ReactTree needs to access the state.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an example using states and not state management systems.**

Let's assume that we've got 2 sibling components; page1 and page2. If we need to pass data from the page1 component to the page2 component, we can use hooks in react-router-dom v6.

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const Page1 = () => {
  return (
    <Link to={'/page2'} state: {msg: "hello from page1"}>Go to Page2</Link>
  );
}

export default Page1;
```

On the page2 component, you can receive the object like that.

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Page2 = (props) => {
   const { state } = useLocation();
   
   return <div>{state.msg}</div>
 
}

export default Page2;
```