# How to pass a state variable as a prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my top level component App.js that has Quiz.js and Profile.js. I am trying to pass the **result** state variable from Quiz.js to Profile.js to display the users results from taking a quiz. I haven't found any solid instructions or videos on how to change a state variable into a prop in order to pass it to another component. If you give advice please explain! I'm very new to react.

```
function App() {
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Router>
            <NavBar />
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<Quiz />} />
              <Route path='/me' element={<Profile />} />
              <Route path="/profiles/:username" element={<Profile />}/>
            </Routes>

          </Router>
          <Footer />
        </ApolloProvider>
)};


export default App;
```

```
const Quiz = () => {
    const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(QUERY_QUIZ);
    const quizzes = data?.quizzes || [];
    console.log(data)

    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState(null);
    const [isQuizComplete, setIsQuizComplete] = useState(false);
    const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(null);
    const [result, setResult] = useState(0);
    const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState(false);

    if (loading) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    if (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching quiz data:", error);
        return <p>Error fetching quiz data.</p>;
    }

    const { question, answers, correct_answer } = quizzes[currentQuestion];

    const handleNextQuestion = () => {

        //code that gives value to result state variable


    return (
      //lots of code that includes {result}
};

export default Quiz;
```

I tried adding the results to App.js like below and also tried acting like it was a normal prop.

```
<Route path='/' element={<Quiz result={result} setResult={setResult}/>} />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Lift State Up w/ React Router 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75658306/how-to-lift-state-up-w-react-router-6)

Comment: Additionally you could always use a state manager like redux.